# When should I use GC.SuppressFinalize()?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, idisposable, suppressfinalize

In .NET, under which circumstances should I use `GC.SuppressFinalize()`?

What advantage(s) does using this method give me?

Comment: I have seen a few questions about finalizers and IDisposable, stackoverflow should also have something about GC.SupressFinalize and weak references

Comment: I don't think weak references do much of anything regarding finalizers - maybe you should post a more direct question about them.

Comment: Yerp I was meaning to post a separate question about weak refs, all of this can tie together when you build object pools. Also I should ask a question about object revival ala ReRegisterForFinalize

Answer (score 392, accepted):

`SuppressFinalize` should only be called by a class that has a finalizer. It's informing the Garbage Collector (GC) that `this` object was cleaned up fully.

The recommended `IDisposable` pattern when you have a finalizer is:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // called via myClass.Dispose(). 
                // OK to use any private object references
            }
            // Release unmanaged resources.
            // Set large fields to null.                
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() // Implement IDisposable
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~MyClass() // the finalizer
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Normally, the CLR keeps tabs on objects with a finalizer when they are created (making them more expensive to create). `SuppressFinalize` tells the GC that the object was cleaned up properly and doesn't need to go onto the finalizer queue. It looks like a C++ destructor, but doesn't act anything like one.

The `SuppressFinalize` optimization is not trivial, as your objects can live a long time waiting on the finalizer queue. Don't be tempted to call `SuppressFinalize` on other objects mind you. That's a serious defect waiting to happen.

Design guidelines inform us that a finalizer isn't necessary if your object implements `IDisposable`, but if you have a finalizer you should implement `IDisposable` to allow deterministic cleanup of your class.

Most of the time you should be able to get away with `IDisposable` to clean up resources. You should only need a finalizer when your object holds onto unmanaged resources and you need to guarantee those resources are cleaned up.

Note: Sometimes coders will add a finalizer to debug builds of their own `IDisposable` classes in order to test that code has disposed their `IDisposable` object properly.

```
public void Dispose() // Implement IDisposable
{
    Dispose(true);
#if DEBUG
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
#endif
}

#if DEBUG
~MyClass() // the finalizer
{
    Dispose(false);
}
#endif
```

Comment: I agree with your code but I would put an assert into the debug version...and if the resource being disposed was expensive, I would leave the finalizer in the release verion.

Comment: In the first code snippet I'm just posting what the recommended IDisposable + finalizer pattern looks like. Debugging code is good, but it can be distracting. ..  I can only recommend avoiding finalizers except for classes that have unmanaged resources. Writing safe finalizer code is non-trivial.

Comment: Can I use disposing pattern in a base class and extend it among others one?

Comment: @Eduardo, yes you can absolutely. The recommended Dispose method is `protected virtual` for this reason, and follows what is called the NVPI pattern (Non Virtual Public Interface). Just make sure you document how subclasses should implement IDisposable and you're set.

Comment: Hi, Why do we need to call dispose with false as parameter from finalizer? What if the dispose never got called and then it wont dispose? What if we just check for whether the object has been disposed or not and do the actual cleanup.

Comment: In other words, do we really need disposing parameter in protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)? can anyone please explain? i think the variable disposed is good enough.

Comment: @Dreamer - it depends on your implementation. In general you want to know if Dispose is being called by the finalizer versus the IDisposable.Dispose() implementation. If called from the finalizer, you must assume private references are no longer valid, and you really can't do much. If however called from IDisposable.Dispose(), you know that references are still valid.

Comment: If the class implementing `IDisposable` is not `sealed`, then it should include the call to `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` *even if it does not include a user-defined finalizer*. This is necessary to ensure proper semantics for derived types that add a user-defined finalizer but only override the protected `Dispose(bool)` method.

Comment: Thanks @280Z28 - do you have any further references that others might find helpful?

Comment: @Robert - if private references aren't valid, what *can* I do that is likely to be of any use? It seems unusual to have a "pattern" in common use that doesn't appear to have common benefits.

Comment: @bacar Managed references are assumed to be invalid at that point, but unmanaged resources can still be freed. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx - I'll update the answer

Comment: Not being `sealed` as mentioned by @SamHarwell is important, for the derived classes. CodeAnalysis results in ca1816+ca1063 when class is not sealed, but sealed classes are fine without `SuppressFinalize`.

Answer (score 55):

`SupressFinalize` tells the system that whatever work would have been done in the finalizer has already been done, so the finalizer doesn't need to be called.  From the .NET docs:

> Objects that implement the IDisposable
>   interface can call this method from
>   the IDisposable.Dispose method to
>   prevent the garbage collector from
>   calling Object.Finalize on an
>   object that does not require it.

In general, most any `Dispose()` method should be able to call `GC.SupressFinalize()`, because it should clean up everything that would be cleaned up in the finalizer.

`SupressFinalize` is just something that provides an optimization that allows the system to not bother queuing the object to the finalizer thread. A properly written `Dispose()`/finalizer should work properly with or without a call to `GC.SupressFinalize()`.

Comment: *A properly written Dispose()/finalizer should work properly with or without a call to GC.SupressFinalize()* - Out of interest, is there any reason why it's recommended that `SupressFinalise` is recommended, these days (2022/C# 10+)?

Answer (score 6):

```
Dispose(true);
GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
```

If object has finalizer, .net put a reference in finalization queue.

Since we have call `Dispose(true)`, it clear object, so we don't need finalization queue to do this job.

So call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` remove reference in finalization queue.

Comment: IMO this is an anti-pattern. At best it falls into the premature optimization bracket. Is the finalisation queue a bottle neck in your system, unlikely. Does doing this wrong have performance issues, yes. So the "cure" is worse than the disease.

Answer (score 2):

If a class, or anything derived from it, might hold the last live reference to an object with a finalizer, then either `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` or `GC.KeepAlive(this)` should be called on the object after any operation that might be adversely affected by that finalizer, thus ensuring that the finalizer won't run until after that operation is complete.

The cost of `GC.KeepAlive()` and `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` are essentially the same in any class that doesn't have a finalizer, and classes that do have finalizers should generally call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`, so using the latter function as the last step of `Dispose()` may not always be necessary, but it won't be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

That method must be called on the `Dispose` method of objects that implements the `IDisposable`, in this way the GC wouldn't call the finalizer another time if someones calls the `Dispose` method.

See: [GC.SuppressFinalize(Object) Method - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.suppressfinalize)

Comment: I think "Must" is wrong - not even "should" - It's just that in some scenarios, you can eliminate the overhead of queueing/finalizing the object.