# What does the Dispose method do in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

When I write a mail delivery service, I find the 'Dispose()' function:

```
private void InnerDisposeMessage(MailMessage message)
        {
            if (message != null)
            {
                if (message.AlternateViews.Count > 0)
                {
                    message.AlternateViews.Dispose();
                }

                message.Dispose();
                message = null;
            }
        }
```

And I track to the `Dispose()` function(`message.AlternateViews.Dispose();)`, here it is:

```
 public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                foreach (AlternateView view in this)
                {
                    view.Dispose();
                }
                base.Clear();
                this.disposed = true;
            }
        }
```

And I track to the view.Dispose() function, here it is:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && !this.disposed)
            {
                this.disposed = true;
                this.part.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

And I track to the    this.part.Dispose(); function, here it is:

```
 public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this.stream != null)
            {
                this.stream.Close();
            }
        }
```

And I track to the stream:

```
public virtual void Close()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
```

and the SuppressFinalize:

```
public static void SuppressFinalize(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
            }
            _SuppressFinalize(obj);
        }
```

But how the resource to be released?  I just understand to invoke the Garbage Collection to release, but how?

I know this question is not easy to understand, but I just want to try!

What the GC.SuppressFinalize(this) function do?

Comment: FYI, `Dispose` is not part of C#. It is part of .NET, which is not the same thing.

Comment: I am voting to leave open, because this is not a design pattern question like the linked duplicate.

Comment: Great. Find one of the other 999 questions this is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption that the code you found "invokes the Garbage Collection to release" the underlying resource is not correct.

At the core, your message uses a [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx). `SuppressFinalize` is not what you are looking for (if you are interested, it just sets a flag for the GC, and more details are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151051/when-should-i-use-gc-suppressfinalize)). But,  you are really looking for the implementation of `Dispose` of the stream that you are using. A stream allows you to read or write data to/from some source or destination.

There are many different kinds of Streams. All a stream does is wrapping some sort of resource, such as files on disk, network, on a web server, mail server, on printers, in memory or pretty much any sort of data resource a computer has to offer. So, the `Dispose` method usually just "closes" the resource (it closes, for example, the file or network connection that the stream used).

Most streams open/read/write/close the underlying resource by placing [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call#Categories_of_system_calls) to communicate with the Operating System who is the guy in charge of [maintaining your computer's resources](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~csonline/OS/Lessons/Resources/index.html). If you are interested in the low-level details of that, you might want to read a good book or take an online course on [Operating Systems](https://www.google.com/search?q=operating+system+online+course).