# Does GC.SuppressFinalize() have effect if the object has not Finalizer?

Tags: c#, dispose, finalizer, suppressfinalize

I know that since some version `StreamWriter` stopped support Finalizer, but in [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,233) I see it calls `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`. Why does it call it? I thought it is actually only for the object which has Finalizer.

---

**Update**

I am wondering whether `GC.SuppressFinalize()` has some effect if the object has not Finalizer?

Comment: A more detailed explanation can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151051/when-should-i-use-gc-suppressfinalize

Comment: @AtmanirbharBharat yes, good call. I tagged duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its part of the [dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose).

Microsoft describes the dispose pattern to look like:

```cs
public void Dispose()
{
   // Dispose of unmanaged resources.
   Dispose(true);
   // Suppress finalization.
   GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

To quote the link:

> The `Dispose` method performs all object cleanup, so the garbage collector no longer needs to call the objects' `Object.Finalize` override. Therefore, the call to the `SuppressFinalize` method prevents the garbage collector from running the finalizer. If the type has no finalizer, the call to `GC.SuppressFinalize` has no effect. Note that the actual cleanup is performed by the `Dispose(bool)` method overload.

edit:
Looking further, with regards to DRY, I would `StreamWriter.Close()` just to call `StreamWrite.Dispose()`. Furthermore, `StreamWriter.Close()` seems redundant anyhow, as the base class `TextWriter.Close()` has the same contents! (And that one should directly call `TextWrite.Dispose()`.
But that's just MHO.)